# How to use a portable display with an older Macbook 2011 (USB 2.0)

Tags: display, usb, thunderbolt

I've been looking at the Asus Zenscreen portable displays to add a second screen to my Macbook Air. ([Model 1](https://www.asus.com/us/Commercial-Monitors/MB169BPlus/), [Model 2](https://www.asus.com/us/Monitors/MB16AC/))

The problem that I'm running into is that it's a USB-C connection, or alternatively you can convert that to USB 3.0.

My Macbook Air only has USB 2.0.

Is there any way to go from USB-C to either my Thunderbolt, or USB 2.0?

Some reviews that I read say that USB 2.0 will work, but the brightness and color might be affected. Others said that there might be latency issues (like noticeable lag).

Is there was some type of adapter or converter that I could use to make this work?

Comment: Hi Derek and welcome to Apple.SE. As I think the proposed connection will not work (see my answer) I think you can better ask another question about what sort of external monitors your MacBook does support.

Answer (score 1):

There is a reason for the USB-C / USB 3.0 requirement, and I think it is power (among other factors).

The specifications of those monitors mention 7.5 and 8 Watt. If I understand the [USB wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Power) correctly, USB 2.0 can at most give you 2.5 W (0.5A x 5V), which is not sufficient for your situation.

So even if you find a cable that can physically connect you MacBook to the screen, it will probably not work.